# Редактировать проект на twig

Tags: twig, html, php

Привет! Нужно редизайнить сайт, прислали исходники, а там весь html в twig. К файлу базовой html разметки подключаются другие элементы типа  `{% include 'header.twig' %}`. У меня на ПК php и twig не установлены. Подскажите, что и как надо установить, чтобы файлы twig (если их открывать в браузере как html) отображались корректно, чтобы страница выглядела так, как она будет выглядеть на сайте?

Answer (score 1):

Без веб-сервера твиг не заработает, можно как вариант все через js рендерить, но это мега костыль